# How do I select the first element after an element with a given class?

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, webdriver

In Selenium, how can I select the `li` element immediately after the one with the `pagination_active` class? For example, given the HTML fragment below, I want to get `<li id="1453679100917_11346">`.

```
<div id="search-pagination-wrapper" class="content-item">
  <ol id="1453679100917_11352" class="zsg-pagination">
    <li id="1453679100917_11351">
    <li id="1453679100917_11350">
    <li id="1453679100917_11349">
    <li id="1453679100917_11348" class="pagination_active">
      <a id="1453679100917_11347">6</a>
    </li>
    <li id="1453679100917_11346">
    <li id="1453679100917_11345">
    <li class="pagination-ellipsis">
    <li>
    <li class="pagination-next">
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis:

```
//li[@class='pagination_active']/following-sibling::li[1]
```